# How do i input a string from a buffered reader?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedinputstream

Im used too using Scanner mainly and want too try using a buffered reader:
heres what i have so far

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class IceCreamCone 
{
// variables
String flavour;
int numScoops;
Scanner flavourIceCream = new Scanner(System.in);

// constructor
public IceCreamCone()
{

}
// methods
public String getFlavour() throws IOexception 
{
    try{

    BufferedReader keyboardInput;
    keyboardInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println(" please enter your flavour ice cream");
    flavour  =  keyboardInput.readLine();
    return keyboardInput.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOexception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

im fairly sure  to get an int you can say

```
Integer.parseInt(keyboardInput.readLine());
```

but what do i do if i want a String

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`keyboardInput.readLine()` already returns a string so you should simply do:

```
return keyboardInput.readLine();
```

*(update)*

The `readLine` method throws an `IOException`. You either throw the exception:

```
public String getFlavour() throws IOException {
   ...
}
```

or you handle it in your method.

```
public static String getFlavour() {
    BufferedReader keyboardInput = null;
    try {
        keyboardInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println(" please enter your flavour ice cream");
        // in this case, you don't need to declare this extra variable
        // String flavour = keyboardInput.readLine();
        // return flavour;
        return keyboardInput.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle this
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: im still getting a compile error that way. i dont understand. 

your telling me not too have flavour defined as the string, just a line that will print?

Comment: unhandled io exception. i changed the code too what you gave me above.

Comment: @yu_sha there's no need to be mean. This is obviously a beginner.

Comment: either return flavour or delete the flavour= line

Comment: i tried it that way. i can see what your doing now. i did have a custom exception class called iceCreamConeException but IOexception seems too make more sense. only now its telling me IOexception cannot be resolved too a type.

Comment: It's not IOexception. It's IOException. Notice the capital E. See my updated answer.

Comment: ah, i missed that one. OK i got it now.

thanks for the help bruno.